# JS libraries for product sketching

Tags: javascript, next.js, p5.js, rhino3d, sketching

I need help finding a good JS library that can create a product sketch like this:
[Partition sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKbNP.png). I am using Next.js, and are having toruble with most libraries since Next.js is using SSR and most graphical libraries run client side. I dont need to show the sketch (neccessarrily) to the user, it should just be a downloadble SVG file that are based on the users input from the webpage.

Idealy i want it to be a PDF, that can be send directly to a customer, with all the requireing information and the sketch. Is this possible?

I have tried messing around with Rhino3dm.js and P5.js, but both seem hard to implement with Next.js.

Comment: You can still use client side components with Next.js, but if your approach is completely client side you may not need Next.js at all.

Comment: @Karl-EmilGrarupHertz what is the overall goal you're trying to achieve ? Is it a site where users can upload a .3dm Rhino file and download a PDF/SVG (to allow users without Rhino to access a layout (if the .3dm already set that up) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I want the users to be able to download a .3dm file based on specific mesurements that are present on the site/database. Does that make sense?

Comment: It partially makes sense: you have a database that users can navigate through a site. You want them to be able to download a CAD drawing for the selected product (similar to the image shared). What's unclear is where Rhino fits in. Does the database already contain all these products in 3dm format (if so simply allowing users to download directly should work). If the users need to be able to download a .3dm file the assumption is they will all use Rhino and they might use other CAD packages (or none, just want to print a CAD drawing maybe?). I guess this is where the SVG file comes in ?

Comment: If you already have all the .3dm files you could automate exporting svg from rhino and in your database, alongside 3dm you could also have the svg files. The site can then query the right SVG for the product users select from the database and serve that for download. (This would be server side). (You mentioned Rhino3dm.js but how would that work ? Users first download a .3dm file, then go a page that uses that uses Rhino3dm.js to load the file and hopefully convert/export to svg ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza The products is not in .3dm format. The measurements are being calculated in cloud when the users have entered the product information, then after the calculations the site receives the measurements and draws it for the user using p5, the problem is that p5 is exportet in PNG and the designers/producers wants to have the format in SVG, so that it can be edited after the automatic calculations. And if it is possible .3dm format would be even better cause they're using rhino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [p5.svg renderer](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg) you could try to essentially draw the same measurements/lines in p5, but render to SVG directly instead of canvas (completely bypassing the .3dm format). The library seems to lack updates recently, but you can start with an older version/example like [this one](https://editor.p5js.org/joshuaebutters/sketches/hPmzp-gTi) and copy it/modify to prototype what you need.

If .3dm is even better, you shouldn't need p5.js at all: the rhino3dm js library should handle both drawing lines/curves/text (if you have the input from the user) and save to .3dm.

You can check out the [SampleSketch2d](https://mcneel.github.io/rhino-developer-samples/rhino3dm/js/SampleSketch2d/) live example. ([source](https://github.com/mcneel/rhino-developer-samples/blob/7/rhino3dm/js/SampleSketch2d/script.js))

[image: rhino3dm example drawing 2d curves on a 2D viewport (with x axis in red, y axis in green and the typical rhino light gray background and dark gray square grid)]

You can run the same example bellow as well)

```js
const downloadButton = document.getElementById("downloadButton")
downloadButton.onclick = download

// global variables
let _model = {
  // saved nurbs curves
  curves: [],
  // new nurbs curve
  points: null,
  // viewport for canvas
  viewport: null,
}


// wait for the rhino3dm web assembly to load asynchronously
let rhino
rhino3dm().then(async m => {
  console.log('Loaded rhino3dm.')
  rhino = m // global
  run()
})
/**/

// initialize canvas and model
function run() {
  let canvas = getCanvas()
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
  window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)
  _model.points = new rhino.Point3dList()
  _model.viewport = new rhino.ViewportInfo()
  _model.viewport.screenPort = [0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight]
  _model.viewport.setFrustum(-30,30,-30,30,1,1000)
  draw()
}

function download() {
  if(_model.curves.length<1){
    console.log('no curves')
    return
  }

  let doc = new rhino.File3dm()
  for(let i=0; i<_model.curves.length;i++) {
    doc.objects().add(_model.curves[i], null)
  }

  let options = new rhino.File3dmWriteOptions()
  options.version = 7
  let buffer = doc.toByteArray(options)
  saveByteArray("sketch2d"+ options.version +".3dm", buffer)
  doc.delete()
}

function saveByteArray(fileName, byte) {
  let blob = new Blob([byte], {type: "application/octect-stream"})
  let link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  link.download = fileName
  link.click()
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  interaction   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

// handles mouse down events
// adds a new control point at the location of the mouse
function onMouseDown(event) {
  // get the location of the mouse on the canvas
  let [x,y] = getXY(event)

  // if this is a brand new curve, add the first control point
  if (_model.points.count === 0) {
    _model.points.add(x, y, 0)
  }

  // add a new control point that will be saved on the next mouse click
  // (the location of the previous control point is now frozen)
  _model.points.add(x, y, 0)
  draw()
}

// handles mouse move events
// the last control point in the list follows the mouse
function onMouseMove(event) {
  let index = _model.points.count - 1
  if (index >= 0) {
    let [x,y] = getXY(event)
    _model.points.set(index, [x, y, 0])
    draw()
  }
}

// handles key up events
function onKeyUp( event ) {
  switch ( event.key ) {
    // when the enter key is pressed, save the new nurbs curve
    case "Enter":
      if (_model.points.count < 4) { // 3 pts (min.) + next pt
        console.error('Not enough points!')
      } else {
        // remove the last point in the list (a.k.a. next)
        let index = _model.points.count - 1
        _model.points.removeAt(index)

        // construct a curve from the points list
        let degree = _model.points.count - 1
        if (degree > 3)
          degree = 3

        // construct a nurbs curve
        // (first arg == true to create a closed periodic uniform curve)
        _model.curves.push(rhino.NurbsCurve.create(true, degree, _model.points))
      }

      // clear points list
      _model.points.clear()
      
      // enable download button
      downloadButton.disabled = false
      break
  }
  draw()
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  helpers   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

// gets the canvas
function getCanvas() {
  return document.getElementById('canvas')
}

// gets the [x, y] location of the mouse in world coordinates
function getXY(evt) {
  let canvas = getCanvas()
  let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x = evt.clientX - rect.left
  let y = evt.clientY - rect.top
  let s2w = _model.viewport.getXform(rhino.CoordinateSystem.Screen, rhino.CoordinateSystem.World)
  let world_point = rhino.Point3d.transform([x,y,0], s2w)
  s2w.delete()
  return [world_point[0],world_point[1]]
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  drawing   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

// clears the canvas and draws the model
// for some reason removing semicolons causes an error in this method
function draw() {
  // get canvas' 2d context
  let canvas = getCanvas();
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let w2s = _model.viewport.getXform(rhino.CoordinateSystem.World, rhino.CoordinateSystem.Screen);

  // clear and draw a grid
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(130,130,130)';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for(let i=0; i<50; i+=1){
    let [x,y] = rhino.Point3d.transform([i,-50,0], w2s);
    let [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([i,50,0], w2s);
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    [x,y] = rhino.Point3d.transform([-i,-50,0], w2s);
    [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([-i,50,0], w2s);
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);

    [x,y] = rhino.Point3d.transform([-50, i, 0], w2s);
    [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([50, i, 0], w2s);
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    [x,y] = rhino.Point3d.transform([-50, -i, 0], w2s);
    [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([50, -i, 0], w2s);
    ctx.moveTo(x,y);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  }
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(150,75,75)';
  let [x,y] = rhino.Point3d.transform([0,0,0], w2s);
  let [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([50,0,0], w2s);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x,y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(75,150,75)';
  [x1,y1] = rhino.Point3d.transform([0,50,0], w2s);
  ctx.moveTo(x,y);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw saved nurbs curves
  for (let i=0; i<_model.curves.length; i++)
    drawNurbsCurve(ctx, _model.curves[i], w2s);

  // create a temporary curve from the points and draw it
  if (_model.points !== null && _model.points.count > 0) {
    let degree = _model.points.count - 1;
    if (degree > 3)
      degree = 3;
    let curve = rhino.NurbsCurve.create(true, degree, _model.points);
    drawNurbsCurve(ctx, curve, w2s);

    // draw control polygon from the temp curve's control points
    //drawControlPolygon(ctx, curve.points());
    drawControlPolygon(ctx, _model.points);

    // delete the temp curve when we're done using it
    // (webassembly memory management isn't great)
    curve.delete();
  }

  w2s.delete();
}

// draws a nurbs curve
function drawNurbsCurve(ctx, curve, w2s) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 1
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'

  const divisions = 200 // TODO: dynamic
  ctx.beginPath()

  let [t0,t1] = curve.domain
  let world_point = curve.pointAt(t0)
  let screen_point = rhino.Point3d.transform(world_point, w2s)
  ctx.moveTo(screen_point[0],screen_point[1])
  for (let j=1; j<=divisions; j++) {
    let t = t0 + j / divisions * (t1-t0)
    world_point = curve.pointAt(t)
    let screen_point = rhino.Point3d.transform(world_point, w2s)
    ctx.lineTo(screen_point[0],screen_point[1])
  }
  ctx.stroke()
}

// draws a control polygon
function drawControlPolygon(ctx, points) {
  // draw dashed lines between control points
  ctx.strokestyle = 'darkgray'
  ctx.setLineDash([4,4])
  ctx.beginPath()

  let w2s = _model.viewport.getXform(rhino.CoordinateSystem.World, rhino.CoordinateSystem.Screen)
  for (let i=0; i<points.count; i++) {
    let world_point = points.get(i)
    let screen_point = rhino.Point3d.transform(world_point, w2s)
    if (0 === i)
      ctx.moveTo(screen_point[0], screen_point[1])
    else
      ctx.lineTo(screen_point[0], screen_point[1])
  }
  if( points.count > 2 ){
    let world_point = points.get(0)
    let screen_point = rhino.Point3d.transform(world_point, w2s)
    ctx.lineTo(screen_point[0], screen_point[1])
  }

  ctx.stroke()

  // draw control points
  ctx.setLineDash([])
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
  for (let i=0; i<points.count; i++) {
    let world_point = points.get(i)
    let screen_point = rhino.Point3d.transform(world_point, w2s)
    let [x,y,z] = screen_point
    ctx.fillRect(x-1,y-1, 3, 3)
    ctx.strokeRect(x-2, y-2, 5, 5)
  }
  w2s.delete()
}
```

```html
<div id="description">
  Click on the canvas to create a NURBS curve and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and start a new one!
</div>
<button id="downloadButton" disabled>Download</button> 
<div>
  <canvas class="rhino3dm" id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rhino3dm@7.15.0/rhino3dm.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

In the above example the download button will be sanboxed, but running on a local webserver should be fine.

(One final note, if for some reason you need to use p5 **and** rhino3dm (though performance may vary), you can access p5's [`drawingContext`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/drawingContext) to get the the sketch's underlying Canvas render (when not using the SVG renderer) to draw the same as the above in a sketch's canvas).